# Node https server crashing: `undefined` path in fs.readFile()

Tags: node.js, https, node.js-fs

I'm setting up an https server but as soon as I access the root `/` the service crashes (after retrieving the html file successfully). The error is generated as per the debugger in the `fs.readFile` function. I think it might be associated with the `event loop` as I know the fs.readFile is async, but I can't get myself to figure out the actual flow.

Does anyone know what my problem is?

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'key.pem')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'cert.pem')),
};

https
    .createServer(options, (req, res) => {
        let resource;
        switch (req.url) {
            case '/': {
                resource = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist/index.html');
                break;
            }
        } 
        fs.readFile(resource, (err, data) => {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    })
    .listen(8080, () => console.log('Server is running. Yes.'));
```

Documentation is very welcome.

The specific error is `'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'` the path argument, `resource`, is undefined, but as it works the 'first round' I guess is about flow. I am positive `req.url` is `/`, so the resource assignment must have taken place.

I thank you for your help in advance, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I'm an idiot, there is a linked css file in the html, so the callback function is being immediately recalled, and the value of `req.url` is `/style.css` the second time, so the value of `resource` just stays undefined.

Comment: Yeah, you MUST add a `default` to your switch and handle the case where the path is not something you're expecting.